# trying to write HTTP_REFERER to referer.txt but it's not working

Tags: php, javascript, apache, tracking, referrer

I have several questions. I working within Joomla. I am trying to use this php code to write the referrer to referer.txt but I cannot find 'referer.txt' anywhere in joomla:

```
<?php 
$referer = get_en("HTTP_REFERER");
if($referer){
$fp=fopen("referer.txt","a")||die("Could not open referer file!");
fwrite($fp,$referer);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

The page on staging does not throw any errors in firebug however.

The bosses want a record of referrers to a specific page ( I am using this specific page as a test. It is not the target page).

My questions are:

1. If the above code is not failing, where the heck could referer.txt be in a joomla system?
2. Is there another way of doing this? For example, this page http://www.webvanta.com/post/248869-using-referrer-urls-to-better-understand suggest using javascript to build cookies to track referrers, and this site http://webdesign.about.com/cs/loganalysistools/a/aaloganalysis.htm suggests using web logs and log analysis tools.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't `get_en("HTTP_REFERER")` be `get_env("HTTP_REFERER")`?

Comment: You need to specify the full path to referer.txt

Comment: Hi Mathieu, yes it should be get_env my bad typing. PitaJ thanks, i will try to set the full path

Answer (score 2):

The first line, `$referer = get_en("HTTP_REFERER");` is using `get_en()`, but the built-in function is [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php).

Another way to access the current user's referrer would be through the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'];` parameter - though according to the documentation this is the same as using `getenv()`.

A server-side method to track the referrers would be to parse the [access_log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html) files created by Apache. These logs will offer you request dates, request types (GET, POST, etc), files, query strings, IPs, UserAgents, and a slew of other informative parts.

Regarding where the `referer.txt` file is being stored, you should open it using an absolute path. You can use `$fp=fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/referer.txt', 'a');`, or set a custom path such as `$fp=fopen("/tmp/referer.txt", 'a');`.